# Java - Expected output after a loop printing array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I've seen this question (from a multiple choice) "what is the output of the following program" :

```
class array_output {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        int array_variable [] = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            array_variable[i] = i/2;
            array_variable[i]++;

            System.out.print(array_variable[i] + " ");
            i++;
        }
    } 
}
```

The expected output is:

> 1 2 3 4 5

It is clear to me that the value `i` is incremented twice, first in the body of the loop and at the last line.
But I don't really get what the line `array_variable[i]++;` is doing.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance to answer to this newbie question!

Comment: `something++` can be read `something = something + 1`

Answer (score 1):

The post-fix increment and decrement operators return the value of a variable before altering its value. Consider the following:

```
int anInt = 0;
System.out.println("anInt: " + anInt);
// anInt: 0
System.out.println("anInt: " + anInt++);
// anInt: 0
System.out.println("anInt: " + anInt);
// anInt: 1
System.out.println("anInt: " + ++anInt);
// anInt: 2
System.out.println("anInt: " + anInt);
// anInt: 2
```

So basically, `anInt++` returns the value of `anInt` before incrementing it. `++anInt` increments the value of `anInt` before returning the (freshly-incremented) value.

Answer (score 0):

`array_variable[i]++;` increments the value that is stored in `array_variable[i]` by one.